# ObservableCollection and LongListSelector

Tags: c#, data-binding

My application consists in navigating between five pages. Each page contains a list. All lists display equivalent contents, using LongListSelector, and binding an ObservableCollection :

```
public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
}
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; private set; }
    ...
}
```

I want to maintain only one xaml page : all the list must always look the same and I don't want to change 5 pages each time I retouch the design. So, I created 5 other objects ObservableCollection, and when I change the page, the object Items is set to one of them.

But since I did that, I do not have anything displayed any more, as if the lists were empty. I put a breakpoint to check that these lists had been filled, and they are.

I tried to fill Items itself, first. It is displayed. But the following instruction results in clearing the list from the screen :

```
this.Items = this.ItemsList1;
```

I tried to implement the event CollectionChanged, but it changes nothing.

Is it the wrong ways to use it ? Is there another way to bind several sets of data in the same page ?

Comment: We need more code to find the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not raised the `PropertyChanged` event when you change you `Items` property. Either add a backing field and do it in the property setter, or just fire it after you assign `Items`. eg.

```
this.Items = this.ItemsList;
RaisePropertyChanged("Items"); //or however you've implemented INPC
```

Comment: I added this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Items") and it works. Thanks !